# Sort a List with OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following model

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        public String CVR_Nummer { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public String FirmaNavn { get; set; }
        public int ProcentAnswered { get; set; }
    }
```

I create a `List<UserViewModel>` and try to sort it:

```
userviewmodel.OrderBy(x => x.ProcentAnswered);
```

It compiles, but the list doesnt get sorted. Howcome?

Comment: how you know that list is **not** sorted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is side-effect free by design so it won't change the input. Also it uses lazy execution, it won't do anything till you try to reach the data. Re-assign the output to the list and it should work. Notice that I'm using ToList() method here because OrderBy() returns `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>` and it's not evaluated till we try to get the items in it. We create a new list from this sequence using ToList() method and forcing the query to execute.

```
userviewmodel = userviewmodel.OrderBy(x => x.ProcentAnswered).ToList();
```

Comment: I would say "side-effect free by *design*".

Answer (score 3):

Linq queries are executed lazily, which means that they do not execute until the source object is **enumerated**. Moreover, the query never operates on the actual object in place, but returns a new instance.

To force execution on the spot., you must explicitly call `.ToList()` after creating the query:

```
userviewmodel = userviewmodel.OrderBy(x => x.ProcentAnswered).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

In this `userviewmodel.OrderBy(x => x.ProcentAnswered);` you have just **prepared the query**, you even **didn't sorted your list**.

In this `userviewmodel.OrderBy(x => x.ProcentAnswered).ToList();` you have **fired the query**, and have sorted list, but above expression will **give you a fresh list**.

So you will need to do this

```
userviewmodel = userviewmodel.OrderBy(x => x.ProcentAnswered).ToList();
```

as suggested by everyone.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
userviewmodel = userviewmodel.OrderBy(x => x.ProcentAnswered).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
userviewmodel.OrderBy(x => x.ProcentAnswered);
```

That's an expression, not an instruction to modify something. The value of the expression is your sorted list but you are not capturing it in a variable, and LINQ expressions are lazy-evaluated, so because you do not capture the result thereby forcing it to resolve, this statement has no effect whatsoever.